# How to sort Javascript arrays in a dictionary

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, dictionary

If I have a dictionary of arrays, for example:

```
samples = {
   "labels": ["A", "B", "C"],
   "values": [2, 3, 1]
}
```

How do I sort the lists by the value order? For example, the output would be:

```
samples = {
   "labels": ["C", "A", "B"],
   "values": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Would I need to convert the dictionary of lists into a list of dictionaries, sort by the values, then convert back, or is there a more direct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take the indices and sort these and then get the mapped arrays by using the sorted indices.

```js
var samples = { labels: ["A", "B", "C"], values: [2, 3, 1] },
    indices = [...samples.values.keys()];

indices.sort((a, b) => samples.values[a] - samples.values[b]);

samples.labels = indices.map(i => samples.labels[i]);
samples.values = indices.map(i => samples.values[i]);

console.log(samples);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Thanks! I was also able to extend it to sorting additional lists in the dictionary by adding more maps.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this all in place.

First we `map` a new array giving us [{label, value}]
Then we `sort` on the `value`
Finally we use `reduce` to rebuild to our original object.

```js
let samples = {
   "labels": ["A", "B", "C"],
   "values": [2, 3, 1]
}

samples = samples.labels
       .map((label, i) => ({ label, value: samples.values[i] }))
       .sort(({ value: a }, { value: b }) =>  a - b)
       .reduce((a, { value, label }) => {         
          a.labels.push(label);
          a.values.push(value);
          return a;
       }, { labels: [], values: []});

console.log(JSON.stringify(samples));
```